# How do I split a batch of promises so they don't hit the API requests per second limit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have a very large number of API requests I would like to make (~1500), but TMDB has a per second request limit of 50. I'd like to send the requests in batches or delay them somehow but I can't figure out how to do so. My goal is to be able to search a name and find every character with that name across a specific country's shows; however, directly searching by character is not supported by the API.

Currently, I use Promise.all to grab every show with TR as an origin country from TMDB - there are 78 pages so I make 78 requests. Then, I use another Promise.all to grab the aggregate credits for each of the shows (which is around 1560 as of right now) and search the cast for characters with the input name.

Once in a while it works, but more often than not I get 429 (Too Many Requests). This is my first time working with Promise.all, so I'm not sure how to reorganize my code so there's a sufficient delay that will allow me to successfully make all the API requests I need and return the results.

```
export default function CharSearch(){
    const [input, setInput] = React.useState("")
    const [showIds, setShowIds] = React.useState([])
    const [characters, setCharacters] = React.useState([])
    const { promiseInProgress } = usePromiseTracker()

   React.useEffect(()=>{
        Promise.all(Array.from({length: 78}, (_, i) => 
        fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/tv?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_origin_country=TR&page=${i + 1}`).then(r => r.json())
            .then(data => data.results.map(show => ({name: show.original_name, id: show.id})))))
        .then(res => setShowIds(res.flat()))
   }, [])

    function getChars(){ 
        trackPromise(
            Promise.all(Array.from({length: showIds.length}, (_, i) => 
            fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/${showIds[i].id}/aggregate_credits?api_key=${API_KEY}`).then(r => r.json())
                .then(data => data?.cast.filter(person => removeDiacritics(person.roles[0].character).startsWith(input)).map(person => (
                    {character: person.roles[0].character, name: person.name, show: showIds[i].name, profile: person.profile_path}))
                    )))
            .then(res => setCharacters(res.flat()))            
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
              })
        )
    }

    function handleClick(){
        getChars()     
    }

    function removeDiacritics(str){
        return str.normalize("NFKD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")
    }

    return(
        <div className="CharacterSearch" >
            <div className="search" >
                <div className="search-inputs">
                    <input type="text" value={input || ""} placeholder="Search character" onChange={((e)=>setInput(removeDiacritics(input==="" ? e.target.value.toUpperCase() : e.target.value)))}/>
                    <button className="search-icon" disabled={promiseInProgress ? true : false} onClick={handleClick}> 
                        <SearchIcon /> 
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div style={{height: "400px", width: "800px", marginTop: "80px", textAlign: "center"}}>
                    <h3>Characters</h3>
                    {(promiseInProgress === true) ? <ClipLoader /> : null}

                    {characters.map((person)=>{
                        return( <CharacterCard key={`${person.name}-${person.character}-${person.show}`} {...person}/> )
                    })}
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    )
}
```

Comment: It can certainly be throttled, but I question if this is an ethical use of the API. In about 10 seconds I found this excerpt from their terms and conditions of API usage: "You must not Use, or create any Application that, in Our sole discretion, (i) uses an excessive amount of bandwidth, (ii) degrade or impairs, including in part, access to, or use of, TMDB, its systems and servers, or the TMDB APIs; or (iii) otherwise adversely impacts the stability of TMDB, its systems and servers, or adversely impacts other users of TMDB or the TMDB APIs.". --- sure seems like the definition of excessive

Comment: @BrianThompson This is for a personal project. There are a couple names where I want to see the list of existing characters and I couldn't think of any better way to get that information, but that's about it - it's not a program I'd be running often or sharing with anyone else. Would that be a problem?

Comment: That definitely at least takes it from fairly black and white to a gray area. I think it would be ok, especially if you did some kind of local caching so that you only had to hit their API's like this once, or at least rarely.

Comment: @BrianThompson Oh that's a great idea! I can definitely store the cast information locally for further searches if I can just hit their API once. If that would be acceptable, do you have any advice for how I could throttle the requests? I don't mind spreading them out over a longer period of time to minimize the impact.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this rate limited queue years ago (don't judge the code, it works fine, open to suggestions for better code)

```
const makeRateLimitedQueue = (perSecond) => {
    const delay = Math.ceil(1000 / perSecond);
    const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    let promise = Promise.resolve(Date.now());
    return (cb) => {
        promise = promise
        .then((lastRun) => wait(Math.max(0, delay + lastRun - Date.now())))
        .then(() => Date.now());
        return promise.then(cb);
    };
}
```

This will ensure anything you add to that queue will not execute until about 1000/rate_per_second milliseconds after the previous call

In your code, you can use it like this

```
const queue = makeRateLimitedQueue(50);

React.useEffect(()=>{
    Promise.all(Array.from({length: 78}, (_, i) => 
        queue(() => 
            fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/tv?api_key=${API_KEY}&with_origin_country=TR&page=${i + 1}`)
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then(data => data.results.map(show => ({name: show.original_name, id: show.id})))
        )
    ))
    .then(res => setShowIds(res.flat()))
}, [])

function getChars() { 
    trackPromise(
        Promise.all(Array.from({length: showIds.length}, (_, i) => 
            queue(() => 
                fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/${showIds[i].id}/aggregate_credits?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
                .then(r => r.json())
                .then(data => data?.cast
                    .filter(person => removeDiacritics(person.roles[0].character).startsWith(input))
                    .map(person => ({character: person.roles[0].character, name: person.name, show: showIds[i].name, profile: person.profile_path}))
                )
            )
        ))
        .then(res => setCharacters(res.flat()))            
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
    )
}
```